# First time plotting anything in R- unexpected results

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

all! New here. Much more comfortable with SQL but working on an R project. I created a point graph that didn't come out as expected. [Here is the code that I entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHWeF.png) [And the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNal5.png)

I guess I was expecting a straight line through? I'm very new to this so bare with me.

I know this is a broad question but any tips/ resources to help me with data visualization using R? Thanks!

Comment: Look up plotting regression lines in ggplot. There must be many worked examples on SO. And it's "bear with me" unless you are a nudist.

Comment: This is a very useful link: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/index.html

Comment: Definitely a nudist, IRTFM. A nudist with glasses.

Comment: @Bloxx THIS IS AWESOME THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `geom_smooth()` rather than `geom_line()`. `geom_line()` will try to draw a line connecting all your individual datapoints, while `geom_smooth()` will fit a trend line to your data, which sounds like what you want. It uses loess by default, but if you literally want a straight line, you can have it fit a linear model instead with the argument `geom_smooth(method = lm)`.